# Error in carouselview windows universal mobile

Tags: xamarin

I have the following problem in Carousel Fri, where in Android and iOS it works, in Windows Universal Mobile gives the following error:

[image: error]

```
EmptyClass k = new EmptyClass();
lista = new List<Dados>();

lista.Add(new Dados
{
    titulo = k.Title1.Substring(1)
});

lista.Add(new Dados
{
    titulo = k.Title2.Substring(1)
});

lista.Add(new Dados
{
    titulo = k.Title3.Substring(1)
});

MAinCarousel.ItemsSource = lista;
```

This is my .xaml layout:

```
<cv:CarouselView x:Name="MAinCarousel" >
  <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding titulo}" FontSize="18" HorizontalOptions="Start" Font="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</cv:CarouselView>
```

Comment: MainCarousel is null in the screenshot that you posted?

Comment: Is not null, I have registered items. Only on Windows Mobile that does not work. Android and Ios function normally

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin's CarouselView has been neglected for quite a while now. I'm pretty sure they have plans to make it stable at some point but for now it's not very usable (at least for me it hasn't been). It's very possible that the updates to UWP have rendered it useless.

I'd advice you to look into a 3rd party CarouselView implementation that not only works but has a wider feature set than what Xamarin provides. Take a look at it here: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Android, iOS and UWP are all supported and the updates keep on coming regularly. On top of all that, the usage is very similar to Xamarin's version.

*Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the project. Just a happy user with three projects utilizing the library.*